# How do I pull Flutter 3.10.7 with subosito/flutter-action?

Tags: flutter, github-actions

I am using GitHub actions to build my Flutter app and I use subosito/flutter-action@v2 to pull down Flutter. I am not able to pull the Flutter version 3.10.7 because it is not setup in a channel. I've tried using the channels 'stable' and 'any' and it still does not work. Is there a way to pull version 3.10.7?

```
Run subosito/flutter-action@v2
Run $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/setup.sh -p -c '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/:channel:-:version:-:arch:' -k 'flutter-:os:-:channel:-:version:-:arch:-:hash:' -n '3.10.7' -a 'X64' any
Unable to determine Flutter version for channel: any version: 3.10.7 architecture: x64
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I believe you asked the question on GitHub as well but here's the workaround our team found if anyone else is looking for it: https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action/issues/242#issuecomment-1699782139

Comment: @rhpekarek I think your answer is correct and would be happy to mark it as the correct answer if you change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the original answer from GitHub: https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action/issues/242#issuecomment-1699782139

To solve this we are using this action to set the flutter version to 3.10.6, and then manually changing to the flutter directory and checking out 3.10.7 from there.

```
- name: 'Set Flutter 3.10.6'
   uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
   with:
       flutter-version: 3.10.6
- name: 'Checkout Flutter 3.10.7'
   shell: bash
   run: |
     cd $FLUTTER_ROOT;
     git fetch --tags;
     git checkout 3.10.7;
     flutter --version;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see [flutter 3.10.7](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases/tag/3.10.7) on the branch `flutter-3.10-candidate.1`: that is not part of the [three supported channels](https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action/commit/48cafc24713cca54bbe03cdc3a423187d413aafa): `stable`, `beta`, `master`

So for now, unless specifying directly the [commit e285328](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/e285328a6909879584a27c9b8eec5fa3621ead93), that tag (created 3 weeks ago, mid-Aug. 2023) is not accessible by `subosito/flutter-action@v1`.